# Python - How to track (add/remove) lots of class instances over mulitple iterations?

Tags: python, class, loops, iteration, vtk

I am building a dynamic map of earthquakes, using the vtk library.

I've already made a static one, (see here: https://github.com/yacobuk/QuakeCloud and here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HVdTcI_ozI) so I know the basic idea works, but now I want to try and show the quakes over time.

I have some code examples that show me how to update the frame, and how to add / remove objects, but I'm stuck on figuring out how to spin up an instance, track it for a few periods, then remove it.

The basic add/ remove code looks like this:

```
for point_and_mag in pm.points_mag:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mag = point_and_mag[1]
        point = point_and_mag[0]
        if mag > 2:
            pointCloud = VtkPointCloud(pm)
            pointCloud.addPoint(point, math.log(mag)*10)
            renderer.AddActor(pointCloud.vtkActor)
            renderer.ResetCamera()
            renderWindow.Render()
            time.sleep(0.3)
            renderer.RemoveActor(pointCloud.vtkActor)
            renderer.ResetCamera()
            renderWindow.Render()
```

But of course, this only allows one object at a time (an instance of `pointCloud.vtkActor` via `renderer.AddActor(pointCloud.vtkActor)` waits a while, then removes it with `renderer.RemoveActor(pointCloud.vtkActor)`

How can I add a number of actors (I'm going to use 10 min interval, and there was as many as 5 quakes in that time), tag it with a counter, increment the counter at every loop iteration, and when it reaches 5 iterations, remove the actor?

There is some more context to this question here: [Python/vtk - set each point size individually in a vtkPolyData object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779491/python-vtk-set-each-point-size-individually-in-a-vtkpolydata-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible(*untested*) solution might be:

```
from collections import deque

# The number 5 indicates for how many iterations the actors should be rendered.
rendered_actors = deque([None] * 5, maxlen=5)

for point_and_mag in pm.points_mag:
    if rendered_actors[-1] is not None:
        renderer.removeActor(rendered_actors[-1])
        renderer.ResetCamera()
        renderWindow.Render()

    time.sleep(0.5)
    mag = point_and_mag[1]
    point = point_and_mag[0]
    if mag > 2:
        pointCloud = VtkPointCloud(pm)
        pointCloud.addPoint(point, math.log(mag)*10)
        rendered_actors.appendleft(pointcloud.vtkActor)
        renderer.AddActor(pointCloud.vtkActor)
        renderer.ResetCamera()
        renderWindow.Render()
    else:
        rendered_actors.appendleft(None)
```

This code creates a `deque`(which is a double-linked list) of length 5. The actors are inserted at the left of this deque and at each iteration the rightmost value, if it is an "actor", it is removed from the scene and the scene is re-rendered.

Note that I don't have vtk so I cannot test this code.

---

A small style note: this is really unpythonic code-style:

```
for point_and_mag in pm.points_mag:
    mag = point_and_mag[1]
    point = point_and_mag[0]
```

Use tuple-unpacking:

```
for point, mag in pm.points_mag:
    # ...
    if mag > 2:
        # ...
```

Comment: Ahh, OK. I think I was heading the right direction, the plan being to add each of the points from one time period to a single actor, and then I only have 5 actors to track in the set. I was not aware of the deque idea, and I can see the value of using a rolling buffer/queue to effectively window the live data. Thanks, thats great. I also saw the double unpacking, and thought it was clunkly, I was planning on single unpacking it, but your method is waaaay cleaner - thank you for the tip! Appreciated.

Comment: thats very close, but throws an error when it hits the `is not None` clause - `AttributeError: removeActor`. I took a look at the `rendered_actors[-1]` object, and it seems to be the same object (data inside `pointCloud.vtkActor` == `rendered_actors[-1]`.

Comment: Correction: `renderer.RemoveActor(rendered_actors[-1])`. Works like a charm! Awesome, thanks!