# Efficient way to loop through Numpy data in VTK Python

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to plot 3d point data in vtk by looping through a really large array (size ~ 6e6 x 3). The array shape is (~2000 x 1) with each element containing an array roughly (~3000 x 3)

I used this link as a starting point to plot:

[stackoverflow - update live pointcloud data in vtk python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188762/update-live-pointcloud-data-in-vtk-python)

I run into problems when trying looping through my array however. This is how I'm plotting the array:

```
#pcl is an array ~ size (2000,1) containing arrays that are ~ size (3000, 3)

# for x in range(len(pcl)):  # takes a long time to render output
for x in range(0,10):        # this line renders the first 10 elements
    for point in pcl[x]:
        pointCloud.addPoint(point[:3])
```

How can I go about rendering all the elements in the array in a more efficient way? Ideally it would look like a video playback.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the `addPoint` method you use.

To improve performances, you should not call `InsertNextXXX` methods. Instead `SetNumberOfXXX` and then `SetXXX` with the index.

You should have something like that:

```py
def addPoint(self, idx, point):
...
  self.vtkPoints.SetPoint(idx, point[:])
  self.vtkDepth.SetValue(idx, point[2])
...

def clearPoints(self):
  self.vtkPoints = vtk.vtkPoints()
  self.vtkPoints.SetNumberOfPoints(nbOfPts)
  self.vtkDepth = vtk.vtkDoubleArray()
  self.vtkDepth.SetNumberOfTuples(nbOfTuples)
...
```